# How to set ThreadPool size reasonablely in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

We use the default tomcat container in spring boot. We set the max-thread to 3000.

```
server:
  port: 9805
  tomcat:
    max-threads: 3000
```

In addition, we have used the WebAsyncTask in `Controller` to process request asynchronously, defining another thread pool:

```
ExecutorService executorService = 
   new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 600, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue(1200));
AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(executorService);

public WebAsyncTask<V> execute(final AsyncTask<V> asyncTask) {
        WebAsyncTask<V> webAsyncTask = new WebAsyncTask(this.requestTimeout, this.taskExecutor, asyncTask);
        webAsyncTask.onTimeout(new Callable<V>() {
            public V call() {
                return asyncTask.timeout();
            }
        });
        return webAsyncTask;
    }
```

further more, we used another thread pool in `Service` to fetch some info parallelly:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 200, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10000)
            , new BaseThreadFactory("info-pool"));
```

at last, we use Apache HttpClient to fetch some data:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest.setMaxConnPerRoute(200);
httpRequest.setConnectionRequestTimeout(500);
httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(500);
httpRequest.setMaxConnTotal(500);
httpRequest.setSocketTimeout(1000);
```

The QPS of the system only 200-300.
Where is the bottleneck and how to analyze it ?

Comment: "Where is the bottleneck". A profiler will tell you that.

Comment: Instead of defining such a  large amount of threads (which can actually might even worsen the performance), instead first try to use the default settings